# Testing if current page is the static page set as home page

Tags: homepage

I set my 'About' page as home page, its permalink (my_site/about/) became my_site/ as a result. Is_page('about') returns TRUE on my local server but FALSE on online server.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page).

Put this where you want to check if is frontpage

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
    echo 'I am the frontpage';
}
```

It returns **TRUE** when the main blog page is being displayed and the Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to "Your latest posts", **or when is set to "A static page"**

Comment: Works, thanks Pontus! Just out of curiosity, what could cause the difference of behaviour between local and online servers?

Comment: Maybe you did forget to set the correct template?

Comment: Hmm nope, I am quite sure it was the right template.

Comment: Okey, its hard to say from here. But good its working now :)!